# Full path decleration for a file path used in java for jsp web app

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to be able to have my paths work on any server not just my dev box. 
Right now I declear the full path of the file name as such on my local drive.

```
filename = "H:\test\SourceCode\sample\src\file.txt"

try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            line = in.readLine();
            in.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
             log.error("Exception Message", e);
        }
```

How can I set the file path so when I create the .war file I can use it on any server.  Such as filename = "src/file.txt" (This doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two usual ways:

- `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/..")` - resolves the path relative to the classpath - that is, `WEB-INF/classes` (and jar files)
- `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/..")` resolves the path relative to the webapp root. That is - `webapps/applicationname`